# AWS Aurora-mysql5.7 lower_case_table_name not showing in parameter group

Tags: amazon-rds

I'm trying to convert our mysql to aurora mysql instances and I need the lower_case_table_names setting but am not seeing it in aurora_mysql5.7 parameter groups anymore.  Does anyone know if it was removed or any workarounds?

Tried creating a new parameter group and there is no setting I'm seeing for lower_case_table_names.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter is still available. AWS Aurora has two types of parameter groups : "DB Parameter Group" and "DB Cluster Parameter Group". "lower_case_table_names" parameter is part of DB Cluster Parameter Group.

[image]

You can find more information about that below.

[Aurora MySQL configuration parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Reference.ParameterGroups.html#AuroraMySQL.Reference.Parameters.Cluster)